# Lambdas function Kotlin and type Mismatch

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to port a function from java to kotlin but I'm having quite some problems.
The original java code is this:

```
setOnTaskCompletedListener(task, result -> {
                final String s = result.getText();
                reco.close();
                Log.i(logTag, "Recognizer returned: " + s);
                setRecognizedText(s);
            });

private <T> void setOnTaskCompletedListener(Future<T> task, OnTaskCompletedListener<T> listener) {
    s_executorService.submit(() -> {
        T result = task.get();
        listener.onCompleted(result);
        return null;
    });
}
```

This is my kotlin converted code:

```
private fun <T> setOnTaskCompletedListener(task:Future<T>, listener: OnTaskCompletedListener<T>){
  s_executorService.submit({ 
    val result = task.get()
    listener.onCompleted(result)
  });
}
```

and this is where my code return the error:

```
setOnTaskCompletedListener(task, { result ->
    val s = result.getText()
    reco.close()
    Log.i(logTag, "Recognizer returned: " + s)
    setRecognizedText(s)
  })
```

I keep getting this error over the "{ result -> ... }":

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is (???) -> Unit but OnTaskCompletedListener<???> was expected
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your `setRecognizedText` method is `void` or `Unit` and it's the last expression in this block (so this what will be returned - `Unit` is Kotlin version of `Void`)

In Java code you are returning null - you should do the same however consider thinking about this again because it looks like code smell

Comment: That java code is from the Microsoft cognitive SDK.
I am sincerely not happy with this structure but i am not a kotlin developer so i am trying my best.

The set recognizing text however is actually has unit response

Comment: `The set recognizing text however is actually has unit response` - that's what I'm talking about - this block is expected to return `OnTaskCompletedListener`

Comment: the original function  however does not return anyway a OnTaskCompletedListener so I dont understand why it gives this error.

Comment: It doesn't matter - you have `return null` at the end

Answer (score 0):

If you are turning your code to kotlin, without java interop it would be better to use lambda because it removes use of all boilerplate interfaces.

```
private fun <T> setOnTaskCompletedListener(task:Future<T>, listener: (T) -> Unit){
  s_executorService.submit({ 
    val result = task.get()
    listener(result)
  });
}

//call
setOnTaskCompletedListener(task, { result ->
    val s = result.getText()
    reco.close()
    Log.i(logTag, "Recognizer returned: " + s)
    setRecognizedText(s)
  })
```

**EDIT:**
Since using lambda you can increase efficiency of your application if you use inline modifier

```
inline private fun <T> setOnTaskCompletedListener(task:Future<T>, listener: (T) -> Unit){
```

Comment: this seem to work (no compile error for the moment) but i am not completely sure about this

Answer (score 0):

In the method below, you have mentioned `listener: OnTaskCompletedListener<T>` as an object parameter.

```
private fun <T> setOnTaskCompletedListener(task:Future<T>, listener: OnTaskCompletedListener<T>){
  s_executorService.submit({ 
    val result = task.get()
    listener.onCompleted(result)
  });
}
```

but while actually calling it you are passing a lambda param

```
setOnTaskCompletedListener(task, { result ->
    val s = result.getText()
    reco.close()
    Log.i(logTag, "Recognizer returned: " + s)
    setRecognizedText(s)
  })
```

convert above code by transforming lambda to an anonymous class like this

```
setOnTaskCompletedListener(task,object:OnTaskCompletedListener< /*your T type*/>{ 
    override fun yourInterfaceMethod(result:ResultType) {
        val s = result.getText()
        reco.close()
        Log.i(logTag, "Recognizer returned: " + s)
        setRecognizedText(s)
      }
     })
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it gave me error on the object keyword

Comment: Inside the anonymous class implement the interface method.

Comment: @CristianBregant I have edited my answer. Check it out.